# Laravel Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I've been searching and asking around, but i can't find what i am looking for, or anything similair.

I am looking for a way to pass along certain settings for a user. 
I have a menu in my back-end which the user can narrow or keep wide. Standard the menu is wide. If a user devides to use the narrow menu, and goes to another page, the menu 'resets' to the default wide state. I'd like to pass along this 'setting' with the user.

I know i have to make a cookie. but what else?? no idea.

!IMPORTANT! I am NOT looking for straight answers (which wont teach me anything) I am looking for suggestions on how to do this and if possible a website attached containing some explanation.

Like i said, i know how to make a cookie, but i do not know how to attach it to whatever.

Comment: Not to be too harsh, but a simple look at Laravel's docs would help you...it's a fairly simple task: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies

Comment: @YasenSlavov, that is what i have done before. But it still is unclear to me. As my cookie value can have 2 different values, how to pass this optional value to the cookies value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to use cookies using `queue` method because cookie will be automatically added to response.

You can create multiple cookies for one user but you cannot put optional / different values.

If user will change menu to narrow, you should save cookie with value for example 1, and if he wants menu to be wide again, you can remove the cookie or set it's value to 2.

Each time you load page, you should check if there's a cookie with selected name and if it's value is 1 or different.

Comment: Now that makes sense @Marcin Nabiałek ! Thanks for your input and i will toy around with it. But how to 'save' a cookie? :/

Comment: @Jeroen you didn't want working solution so you should look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies and as I said choose `queue` method to save cookie

Comment: Oh! sorry @Marcin Nabiałek! i meant it differently, i meant: what do you mean with save. I know i didn't want a working solution, just didnt phrase it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel Cookies using**

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('name', 'value', 60);
$response = Response::make('Hello World');

return $response->withCookie($cookie);

or

$cookie = Cookie::make('name', 'value', 60);
$view = View::make('categories.list');

return Response::make($view)->withCookie($cookie);

or

$cookie = Cookie::make('name', 'value', 60);

return Redirect::route('home')->withCookie($cookie);
```